# How do I convert a batch of audio files on Windows?

Tags: audio, batch, sox

I have a folder structure like this:

```
-dir1
    -subdir1
    -subdir2
        -file1.wav
        -file2.wav
-dir2
    -etc...
```

Inside the folders are thousands of audio files that need to be converted. How can I convert them all at once to mp3?  I would like to use the same filenames and keep them in the same folders.  The end result would like this:

```
-dir1
    -subdir1
    -subdir2
         -file1.wav
         -file1.mp3
         -file2.wav
         -file2.mp3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it done with the following command from within the root directory:

```
FOR /R %I IN (*.wav) DO sox %I %~pnI.mp3
```